# DELETE the MIN counted data in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, count, min, collect

I want to delete some data after doing some counting on neo4j. This method can be done manually(counting the data then delete the data), but i need someone to point me whether it's possible or impossible to do this automatically(counting data and delete data in the same query). I couldn't find a way to return the least/minimal data after i did some counting using min() function in neo4j. I can probably do a workaround using order by and limit the data, but i need to be sure that there is no other option than this if i want to do this method.

This is the link to the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KSlH-vTQ57xXUrDXuGLe6USeCmeWYiff/view?usp=sharing). The data is a custom event log that only consists of case_id and activity name.

So this is what i've already tried:

```
//LOAD DATA
LOAD CSV with headers FROM "file:///*.csv"
  AS line
Create (:Activity {CaseId:line.Case_ID,
Name:line.Activity })
LOAD CSV with headers FROM "file:///*.csv"
  AS line
Create (:CaseActivity {CaseId:line.Case_ID,
Name:line.Activity })

//SEQUENCE DISCOVERY
match (c:Activity)
with collect(c) AS Caselist
unwind range(0,Size(Caselist) - 2) as idx
with Caselist[idx] AS s1, Caselist[idx+1] AS s2
match (b:CaseActivity),(a:CaseActivity)
where s1.CaseId = s2.CaseId AND
s1.Name = a.Name AND
s2.Name = b.Name AND
s1.CaseId = a.CaseId AND
s2.CaseId = b.CaseId
merge (a)-[:NEXT {relation:"NEXT"}]->(b)

match(a:Activity) 
with a.CaseId as id, 
collect (a.Name) as Trace_Type 
match(b:CaseActivity) 
where id = b.CaseId 
return count (distinct b.CaseId) as Frequencies, Trace_Type, Collect(distinct b.CaseId) as CaseId 
order by Frequencies desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question did not specify what you wanted to delete. This query assumes that you wanted your last query to delete the `b` nodes (and return some data about the deleted `b` nodes):

```
MATCH (a:Activity) 
WITH a.CaseId as id, COLLECT(a.Name) AS Trace_Type 
MATCH (b:CaseActivity) 
WHERE id = b.CaseId 
WITH
  COUNT(distinct b.CaseId) AS Frequencies,
  Trace_Type,
  COLLECT(distinct b.CaseId) AS CaseId,
  COLLECT(DISTINCT b) AS bs
FOREACH(x IN bs | DELETE x)
RETURN Frequencies, Trace_Type, CaseId
ORDER BY Frequencies DESC;
```

Variables containing values obtained from deleted `b` nodes (like `Frequencies` and `CaseId`) will still be valid after the nodes are deleted.

A tricky thing to note about your specific example is that your last `WITH` clause was using [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/), with `Trace_Type` as the grouping key. In order for my answer to avoid changing the grouping key (and thereby possibly changing your returned results), I just added `COLLECT(DISTINCT b) AS bs` to the `WITH` clause. Then, since each `bs` is a list of `b` nodes (for a `Trace_Type`), I used `FOREACH` to delete the nodes in each list.

Comment: ok, sorry about that, this is my first time using this platform to ask a question

So, what i wanted to delete are all nodes that are inside CaseId that has the least frequencies

Comment: I tried your solution, and it seems to delete all data in CaseActivity labels

Comment: Can you update your question to provide an exact description of what you are trying to do? For example, are you trying to delete all `CaseActivity` nodes that have the least frequent `CaseId` value? And, if so, how exactly do you define "frequency" -- how is `Trace_Type` involved?

Comment: Sorry, i was busy atm. Yeah, exactly as you said, i need to delete all nodes in CaseActivity that have the least Frequencies. So Trace_Type is a collection of CaseActivity.Name, and it doesn't really have to be showed in the return, as long as i can delete the nodes with the least Frequencies. Frequencies is the number of CaseId that have the same Trace_Type.